# Error in creating shared link

Tags: json, curl, box-api

I have uploaded a file into my box account and now when I try to create a shared link for it using cURL, I am getting errors.

> curl https://api.box.com/2.0/files/FILE_ID -H
>   "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" -d '{"shared_link": {"access":
>   "open"}}' -X PUT

The error is as follows:

> {"type":"error","status":400,"code":"bad_request","context_info":{"errors":[{"reason":"invalid_parameter","name":"entity-body","message":"Invalid
>   value '{shared_link:'. Entity body  should be a correctly nested
>   resource attribute name/value
>   pair"}]},"help_url":"http://developers.box.com/docs/#errors","message":"Bad
>   Request","request_id":"144849506852f47c 002e83b"}curl: (3) [globbing]
>   unmatched brace at pos 9 curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close
>   brace/bracket at pos 5

Any thoughts or suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are posting the JSON data using curl. So add this header to let the server know you are sending JSON.

```
-H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Also, if you are using from windows, then use double quote(`"`) around the JSON. For example

```
-d "{test:\"value\"}"
```

If you have problem with secure connection(`https`) then use this parameter as well.

```
-k
```

Comment: Worked like a charm: from DOS prompt I issues the command "curl https://api.box.com/2.0/files/FileId -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer AccessToken" -d "{\"shared_link\": {\"access\": \"open\"}}" -X PUT". I think the Box API documentation should be updated...

Comment: Thanks.  Maybe a link to a curl tutorial and some tips for both Windows and Mac users, since they both have their idiosyncrasy